# Regular Expression for a Max & Min Value on a double

Tags: regex, max, min

I have an MVC3 C#.NET web app.  I have two properties that are doubles and can have the (value >= 0) and (value <=2).  I would like to use a regular expression to limit the values for thes two fields.  Ideas?

Comment: Why do you want to use regular expressions for this and not simply convert the value to a double and then use normal comparison operators?

Comment: I agree with @knittl.  [Read this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xbtzcc4w.aspx) for more information.

Comment: If you really, _really_, __really__ wanted to do it with RegEx, something like this would work ```0*([10]\.\d*|2$|2\.0*$)```

Comment: @Fellas...the reason I want to use RegEx is that it does the validation client side if I apply the Regex to the properties.  Do the comparison operators work client side.  If so, let me know.thx

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand this regex also matches the last 2 from 2.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really don't think regex is a good idea here, but if you want to know …

Let's break it down to what you need to match: 0(.XXXX), 1(.XXX), and 2(.0)

```
var regex = new Regex(@"0*([01](\.[0-9]*)?|2(\.0*)?)");
```

Comment: What about -1.1? What about scientific notation? What abou signs? etc.

Comment: @FailedDev....1.1 is fine scientific is not.  They are just meant to represent percentage multipliers.